# KENDO RECURRENCE EDITOR TRANSLATE WEEK DAYS

Tags: kendo-ui, editor, translation, recurrence

I,
I have a kendoRecurrenceEditor control and i want to translate them.

I follow this example but don't tell me how to translate days like: "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"

http://jsbin.com/ObuFoga/1/edit

Any solution?

Thanks Bruno F.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the current culture should automatically change them. More info can be found in the [globalization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/overview) help topic.

Comment: Thanks Atanas Korchev,
I combine the code that i posted in my question and using you solution i now have all that i want translated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The days are from kendo.culture().calendar.days.  You can over-write them if you need to:

```
// Recurrence Editor uses the 2 character day abbreviations and can't be configured
// overwrite the 2 characters with the 3 to force what we want
var dayInfo = kendo.culture().calendar.days;
for (var i = 0; i < dayInfo.namesAbbr.length; i++) {
    dayInfo.namesShort[i] =  dayInfo.namesAbbr[i];
}
```